# Python: 'self' is missing (not automatically being passed) in object

Tags: python, error-handling

Here is my code:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import os

class Accounts:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_path = os.path.join('lib', 'accounts.xml')

    def get(self, key, value):
        tree = ElementTree.parse(self.file_path)
        print(tree)

accounts = Accounts
accounts.get('k', 'v')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\XML_Build.py", line 15, in <module>
    accounts.get('k', 'v')
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

When I use `accounts.get(key='k', value='v')`, the error says I am missing `'self'`. I have never seen this issue before. How do I pass self? I thought it was passed automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create an instance:

```
accounts = Accounts()  # parenthesis added
```

Otherwise you access the method on the class (which behaves like a normal python function) instead of on the instance (where self is passed implicitly).

Answer (score 3):

You set `accounts` to be an *alias* of the `Accounts` class, but you need to **initialize** it as an *instance* of Accounts:

```
accounts = Accounts()
```

Otherwise, it gets called as a static method, and as such there is no "self" that can be passed (as `self` is always an instance of the class)